# Finding out which item the mouse is over in a list view while using itemssource

Tags: c#, wpf

**Problem:**

When you populate a list view with items source the items are no longer `ListViewItem` They become classes / structs or whatever you used as the `.ItemsSource` Meaning that I can't use the '.IsMouseOver' property on my `PreviewMouseMove` Event

**What Have I Tried?**

1. Casting the `ListViewItem` to a `ListViewItem` and then calling .IsMouseOver on it (Doesn't underline anything but crashes at run time when you put your mouse over the list view, and says 'Cannot cast ClassName to `ListViewItem`)
2. I tried making my class inherit from IInputElement  `public ClassName : IInputElement` Dunno if that's possible or not didn't work says it can't find it I'm kinda new to c# so i dunno how exactly that would work, I'm assuming it has to be a visible element for you to .IsMouseOver it.
3. I tried making my class inherit from `ListViewItem` like `public ClassName : ListViewItem` This worked! but ListViewItem doesn't contain the `.IsMouseOver` property, and it still wouldn't let me cast my class to a ListViewItem without crashing <.<

The overall goal is to highlight a list item and populate a bunch of text fields with the values from the class that the mouse is over and I've done this in winforms before but it's super easy in winforms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should still bind your control to a logical object. While the SelectedItem property is not a ListViewItem, the visual tree will still contain one. Use the VisualTreeHelper and HitTest for the item your mouse is over. Once you have the item, inspect the DataContext property for the bound item.

Here's some code:

```
private ListViewItem FindListViewItem(DragEventArgs e)
{
    var visualHitTest = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(_listView, e.GetPosition(_listView)).VisualHit;

    ListViewItem listViewItem = null;

    while (visualHitTest != null)
    {
        if (visualHitTest is ListViewItem)
        {
            listViewItem = visualHitTest as ListViewItem;

            break;
        }
        else if (visualHitTest == _listView)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found ListView instance");
            return null;
        }

        visualHitTest = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(visualHitTest);
    }

    return listViewItem;
}
```

Another option is to style your ItemsContainerStyle to handle MouseOver the way you want.

Comment: Just working on implementing this, If i get it to work i'll select it

Comment: Ok, It kind of works, but after i get the list view item, how can i cast it to my class? cause (classname)listviewitem says i can't convert listview item to classname .....

Comment: @JustinKirk Once you have the item, inspect the DataContext property for the bound item.

Answer (score 1):

Actually even if you bind your ListView ItemsSource, you will still have ListViewItems in your visual tree. That's what WPF call an item container (like ListBoxItem for example).

You have a property named **ItemContainerGenerator** on your ListView. This will return an ItemContainerGenerator object that has a method called **ContainerFromItem** that will return the ListViewItem associated to you object.

You can then use IsMouseOver on the container you retrieve thanks to the item container generator.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the guy above you gave the same suggestion + code so i selected his answer instead >:D

Comment: Hey, as long as you solved your issue, I'm happy for you ! Cheers !